# How to change filter icon color or filter icon when column is filtered

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have added filterable: true for kendo ui grid. The grid is getting filtered correctly.

What I want is when the filter icon is clicked the filter icon should be filled with some different color or may be the color should be changed for filter icon inidcating that the column filter icon is clicked.

Please tell how to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported out-of-the-box. Take a closer look at the demos when you [filter](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html) change the theme if needed. Or modify the CSS of a particular theme to make it more clearly visible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked it. It is working for me. But the background-color I specified is not getting filled upto entire column height. From top the background color starts but it ends just above the column border, leaving some white space there. So it looks like there is background-color then white space and then the column header border. Can I remove the white space and make the color to end at the header border.

Comment: Thanks. The icon is showing applied background color, But the background color doesn't seems to fill the entire height and so some white space is remaining there, I want to remove the white space that is displayed below the filter icon. How can I remove that.

Comment: I have taken help from above both answers. Thanks to all.

Comment: Why is this the approved answer? There is NO example. I really dislike CSS answers without examples.

Answer (score 7):

In my case the following css did it, easy and simple.

```
.k-grid-filter.k-state-active {
        background-color: #d2691e; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of the themes do this, but at least the Metro one doesn't, if that's the one you're using too.

(with LESS)

```
.k-grid {

    /* Also changes the group row background color */
    .k-grouping-row > td {
        background-color: #c5c5c5;
    }

    .k-grid-header {
        .k-grid-filter.k-state-active {
            background-color: #7ea700; /* Default metro active color */

            /* White icon */
            .k-icon.k-filter {
                background-position: -48px -80px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I grab the kendo.metro.less file, stick that (plus a few others) at the end.

Comment: Thanks. I added the code for the class .k-grid-filter.k-state-active  The icon is showing applied background color. But the background color doesn't seems to fill the entire height and so some white space is remaining there.I want to remove the white space that is displayed below the filter icon. How can I remove that.